# Get values from /proc

Tags: java

I want to get a list of running processes and the values from the /proc filesystem:

This is the structure that I want to search for data for example:

```
/proc/24/status
/proc/344/status
/proc/456/status
.......
```

I made this very quick code:

```
public void initSystemProcesses() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {

        BufferedReader dataReader = null;
        String freeLine;
        String[] freeChunkedLine;
        HashMap<String, String> usageData = new HashMap<>();

        File f = new File("/proc");

        for (File names : f.listFiles())
        {
            if (names.isDirectory())
            {
                File[] subDir = names.listFiles();

                for (File subDirs : subDir)
                {

                    dataReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("subDirs/status")));
                    freeLine = dataReader.readLine();

                    String daemonName = null;
                    String nameValue = null;
                    while (freeLine != null)
                    {
                        freeChunkedLine = freeLine.split("\\s+");
                        String name = freeChunkedLine[0];
                        String value = freeChunkedLine[1];

                        if (name.indexOf("Name:") != -1 || name.indexOf("State:") != -1)
                        {
                            String vv = null;
                            usageData.put(name, vv);
                            if (name.equals("Name:"))
                            {
                                daemonName = vv;
                            }
                            if (name.equals("State:"))
                            {
                                nameValue = vv;
                            }

                            //TODO insert the data into array

                        }

                        freeLine = dataReader.readLine();
                    }

                }

            }
        }

    }
```

The code is not tested and I maybe there are mistakes.

This is the content of the status files:

```
Name:    kthreadd
State:    S (sleeping)
Tgid:    2
Pid:    2
PPid:    0
```

Can you help me to make a effective code which loops the folders and gets the values from the status files?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your real problem, but i guess, that this line could be wrong:

```
dataReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("subDirs/status")));
```

This should be something like:

```
dataReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(subDirs.getAbsolutePath() + "/status")));
```

And the directories should be numeric (for the processes), so add a condition like:

```
if (subDirs.getName().matches("^[0-9]+$")) ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you see some other problems into the code?

Comment: Why don't you just test your code? It's probably easier to find problems, when the compiler or output tells you something!